# Excel multiple values for one key ID

Tags: excel

In Excel I have data set up so column A is a category, column B is an ID. I am trying to figure out how to calculate where a given "Order ID" (Col B) exists in multiple categories (Col A).

[image]

```
Cat ID
Bar 12123
Bar 11111
Foo 12345
Foo 22222
Foo 22222
Foo 88888
Bar 90909
Foo 88888
Bar 90909
Foo 88888
Foo 88888
Bar 90909
Foo 88888
Bar 90909
Foo 90909
Foo 11111
Bar 90909
```

I would like to calculate where a given "ID" exists across multiple "categories", like so:

[image]

```
Cat ID      Example
Bar 12123   FALSE
Bar 11111   TRUE
Foo 12345   FALSE
Foo 22222   FALSE
Foo 22222   FALSE
Foo 88888   FALSE
Bar 90909   TRUE
Foo 88888   FALSE
Bar 90909   TRUE
Foo 88888   FALSE
Foo 88888   FALSE
Bar 90909   TRUE
Foo 88888   FALSE
Bar 90909   TRUE
Foo 90909   TRUE
Foo 11111   TRUE
Bar 90909   TRUE
```

In the example above, I manually typed column C. I am trying to figure out the best way to calculate it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My real world example has several thousand rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS() in C2:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>" & A2,B:B,B2)>0
```

And copy/drag down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>"&A1,B:B,B1)>0`(assuming you are entering this formula in C1).